# Not enough time to manually go through 80000 enteries to copy and paste updated information

Tags: indexing, vlookup

I am not very good with english, computer language, I will try keep this simple and short.
a.  Table 1. 
I have what I call my masterlist, that I store my product, being a unique number, Followed by a lot of other columns, goes up to AC. From Employee name, contractor, employee, company, etc. 61000 rows.
2. I have my customers list, 78900 rows. I made sure our headings are the exact same and in the same column. Some information he has I dont have I left the column blank, but filled the heading in.

Aim - I now would like to 'data from his list to my list. Not to change anything I have, put to full in my blank sections.

I have tried to vlookup, My formula isnt working. 
I have tried index, Keeps saying error. 
I have tried to down load applications from ablebits, not doing what it said it would.

So, Basically. Column A&F must be a match in both sheets, if it is, I wish to Move/copy data from Column d&e in sheet 2 into sheet 1. It is 'start of employment' and 'termination', Not sure if because it dates my formula isnt working

thank you 
Danielle

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirement, perhaps:
1.  Add an index to masterlist (so that later you can sort it back into its original order).
2.  Insert a column (say A) in customers list that concatenates the cells that must match in both sheets, say:

```
=B1&G1
```

3.  Sort masterlist on the column that needs to be populated from customers list (to gather all the blanks together).
4.  For the blank cells apply a formula of the kind:

```
=VLOOKUP(A5000&F5000,masterlist!A$1:A$78900,5,0)
```

Select that column, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top.

5. Repeat 3. And 4. for the other column with a formula of the kind:

   ```
   =VLOOKUP(A6000&F6000,masterlist!A$1:A$78900,6,0)
   ```